# How to position the center of the Glare Node effect (in ghost mode) off center?

Tags: render-layers, compositing-nodes

It seems the Glare node in Ghost mode is always centered in the frame.

I have 2 render layers: 
1 for the Background and the Asteroid (with Object ID). 
2 for a Sun object (A light emitting Sphere with Object ID).

I combine the Background, the Sun with Glare and the Asteroid on top.

When I Translate the Sun Object in the compositor, it affects the Glare, it changes intensity and shape, but it is always centered in the frame, even if the Sun travels from right to left edge of the frame. So it doesn't follow the Sun. It's just in the center.

How to position/control the Glare effect, so that its center follows the Sun traveling from right to left? (Note: I can't just put a Translate Node after the Glare, because the Glare will get clipped at frame edges.)

[image: Glare Node setup and rendered frame]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how lens flare actually works, its an internal reflection of the lens and describes the aperture that the path of light enters. All light passing through a lens goes through the centre at some point. So moving the flare centre around doesn't make physical sense.